# Private IP Disclosure in Aws ECS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ecs

I have a simple dotnet core application running on `AWS` `ECS-ec2` and I recently did a vulnerability checking and it gave me the result

> Private IP Disclosure
> GET :   https://my-domain.com/docs/swagger-ui-bundle.js

How can I mitigate this vulnerability and get rid of it? Is there anything (a header) that I can set from ecs side or should this be **ALWAYS** something to do from Application side?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what generated this message? For example, did it come from a particular application, line of source code, configuration file, etc?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, I added the file where I get this error from

Answer (score 0):

More or less, private IP address disclosure is a low criticality vulnerability. The reason being, disclosing the private IP of other hosts on your computer network will allow for an attacker to expand the attack surface since they now know the connection information of a separate device hosted on the same network. A reason why it is not necessarily a significant security vulnerability is because you can discover that hosts exist on a computer network in any number of ways. However, private IP address disclosure by the server is definitely one of the most common ways an attacker will be able to discover the existence of other hosts on the network. Below demonstrates a sample response where I would see such information leaked and this is likely what is causing the vulnerability:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Location: https://10.100.1.5/owa/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 15:21:02 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

Private IP address disclosure is not a vulnerability that can immediately be exploited since it really only leaks details about your environment that might be able to be used by an attacker in advancing further attacks. Is it sloppy and maybe not best practice? Some might argue this answer, but I would say yes, but the fact of the matter is sometimes the behavior is required for the functionality of the web application to function. The answer of whether you should fix this in your case depends on your business context, is the host you disclosed the private IP to a very sensitive server hosting your most sensitive crown jewels? Well then yes, you shouldn't disclose it and you should fix it. But if it is just some host which is not of much significance, then disclosing the private IP is not sensitive.

As an attacker, I love when applications leak this kind of information and know I can find it in many ways. But where I really advance this is with a SSRF vulnerability. Let's say your application had a server side request forgery (SSRF) vulnerability, an attacker could use this private IP address disclosure to help escalate their attack to what is known as a blind SSRF since they can interact with that host since they know it exists since you disclosed the fact it exists (unless you're spoofing the response to include a fake internal IP, which I doubt considering the current context).

I have had to fix such an error in my past work. There were 2 layers of defense I put.

1. I ran the following command on the IIS server:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime /alternateHostName:"myServer"  /commit:apphost
```

2. I added the following to prevent private IP addresses from ever entering a response ever again:

```xml
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <rewrite> 
            <outboundRules> 
                 <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server"> 
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Content-Location" pattern=".+"/> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" value=""/> 
                 </rule> 
            </outboundRules> 
        </rewrite> 
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.